# setting up apache2/graphite server

Tags: apache2, graphite

I've been trying to make my graphite server work but after reading so many tutorials of how to install and configure everything, I'm still stuck.

At this point, if I use a simple virtualHost, I can see that the apache2 is working fine ("It works!"), but once I enable the other site where the graphite is configured, I get a 503.

could anyone tell me whats wrong in my definitions? Thanks in advance!

```
# the main httpd.conf
#NameVirtualHost *:80

# This line also needs to be in your server's config.
# LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

# You need to manually edit this file to fit your needs.
# This configuration assumes the default installation prefix
# of /opt/graphite/, if you installed graphite somewhere else
# you will need to change all the occurances of /opt/graphite/
# in this file to your chosen install location.

<IfModule !wsgi_module.c>
    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
</IfModule>

# XXvX You need to set this up!
# Read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGISocketPrefix
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName graphite
    DocumentRoot "/opt/graphite/webapp"
    ErrorLog /opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/error.log
    CustomLog /opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/access.log common

    # I've found that an equal number of processes & threads tends
    # to show the best performance for Graphite (ymmv).
    WSGIDaemonProcess graphite processes=5 threads=5 display-name='%{GROUP}' inactivity-timeout=120
    WSGIProcessGroup graphite
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIImportScript /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi process-group=graphite application-group=%{GLOBAL}
    # XXX You will need to create this file! There is a graphite.wsgi.example
    # file in this directory that you can safely use, just copy it to graphite.wgsi
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi

    Alias /content/ /opt/graphite/webapp/content/
    <Location "/content/">
            SetHandler None
    </Location>

    # XXX In order for the django admin site media to work you
    # XXX You need to set this up!
    # Read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGISocketPrefix
    WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName graphite
        DocumentRoot "/opt/graphite/webapp"
        ErrorLog /opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/error.log
        CustomLog /opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/access.log common

        # I've found that an equal number of processes & threads tends
        # to show the best performance for Graphite (ymmv).
        WSGIDaemonProcess graphite processes=5 threads=5 display-name='%{GROUP}' inactivity-timeout=120
        WSGIProcessGroup graphite
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIImportScript /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi process-group=graphite application-group=%{GLOBAL}
        # XXX You will need to create this file! There is a graphite.wsgi.example
        # file in this directory that you can safely use, just copy it to graphite.wgsi
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi

        Alias /content/ /opt/graphite/webapp/content/
        <Location "/content/">
                SetHandler None
        </Location>

        # XXX In order for the django admin site media to work you
        # must change @DJANGO_ROOT@ to be the path to your django
        # installation, which is probably something like:
        # /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django
        Alias /media/ "@DJANGO_ROOT@/contrib/admin/media/"
        <Location "/media/">
                SetHandler None
        </Location>

        # The graphite.wsgi file has to be accessible by apache. It won't
        # be visible to clients because of the DocumentRoot though.
        <Directory /opt/graphite/conf/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ServerName 54.12.34.222`

Give in your public IP there. Why again do you mave multiple VirtualHosts defined in there?

```
<IfModule !wsgi_module.c>
    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
</IfModule>

# XXX You need to set this up!
# Read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGISocketPrefix
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 54.100.200.100
        DocumentRoot "/opt/graphite/webapp"
        ErrorLog /opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/error.log
        CustomLog /opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/access.log common

        # I've found that an equal number of processes & threads tends
        # to show the best performance for Graphite (ymmv).
        WSGIDaemonProcess graphite processes=5 threads=5 display-name='%{GROUP}' inactivity-timeout=120
        WSGIProcessGroup graphite
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIImportScript /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi process-group=graphite application-group=%{GLOBAL}

        # XXX You will need to create this file! There is a graphite.wsgi.example
        # file in this directory that you can safely use, just copy it to graphite.wgsi
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi

        Alias /content/ /opt/graphite/webapp/content/
        <Location "/content/">
                SetHandler None
        </Location>

        # XXX In order for the django admin site media to work you
        # must change @DJANGO_ROOT@ to be the path to your django
        # installation, which is probably something like:
        # /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django
        Alias /media/ "@DJANGO_ROOT@/contrib/admin/media/"
        <Location "/media/">
                SetHandler None
        </Location>

        # The graphite.wsgi file has to be accessible by apache. It won't
        # be visible to clients because of the DocumentRoot though.
        <Directory /opt/graphite/conf/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /opt/graphite/webapp>
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                AllowOverride All
                AuthName "Graphite web access"
                AuthType Basic
                AuthUserFile /opt/graphite/passwd/passwords
                Require user webyog
                Allow from 122.181.14.62, 202.191.170.90 
                Satisfy Any
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```